# How to specify object type in function call

Tags: typescript

If I am calling a function that takes `any` how do I specify the type of an object literal that is passed in directly (without creating a local variable). This doesn't work:

```js
      aMessageChannel.port1.postMessage({
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
      }: MyMessageType);
```

Comment: Why do you need to specify the type of the parameter if the function doesn't require it?

Comment: To ensure I get the object fields correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need to specify an object's type at the place where it is called, you would usually do that in the function definition.

In the case where you are calling an outside function that accepts `any` - and because it's someone else's code you cannot change the function's signature - you can define your object with a type declaration first and then pass it into the function.

```
// if obj does not have the right shape to be a MyMessageType then the error will display here
const obj: MyMessageType = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
}

aMessageChannel.port1.postMessage(obj);
```

Comment: Yes this is an obvious workaround, which is why I specifically said `an object literal that is passed in directly (without creating a local variable)`.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have syntax for that. Sorry.